# How To Parse Complex Numbers In Java

Tags: java

I am trying to accept a string with any of the following variations into my method:

"11+6i"
"11-6i"
"-11-6i"

Using the code I have below, the first two work correctly but for some reason when the string contains two "-" characters I cannot seem to parse it correctly.

Is there anyway to modify my code for it to be able to parse "-11-6i" as well?

Here is my code thus far:

```
if (passedString.contains("+")) {

        int i = passedString.indexOf("+");
        int endIndex = passedString.indexOf("i");

        String real = passedString.substring(0, i);

        String imag = passedString.substring(i, endIndex);

        MyDouble realNum = new MyDouble(Double.parseDouble(real));
        MyDouble imagNum = new MyDouble(Double.parseDouble(imag));

        cn = new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum);

    } else {

        int i = passedString.indexOf("-");

        int endIndex = passedString.indexOf("i");

        String real = passedString.substring(0, i);

        String imag = passedString.substring(i, endIndex);

        MyDouble realNum = new MyDouble(Double.parseDouble(real));
        MyDouble imagNum = new MyDouble(Double.parseDouble(imag));

        cn = new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum);

    }
```

Comment: In your else statement, try switching the `indexOf("-")` with [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29). Right now, your method will pick up the very first `-` character and then your `real` value will be the empty string.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to reuse other's code. Take a look at Apache Commons [Complex Numbers](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html).

Here is an example from their page:

```
ComplexFormat cf = new ComplexFormat();
Complex c = cf.parse("1.110 + 2.222i");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement, if you search for the last index of '-' it will find the second minus sign instead of the first, which is what indexOf does.

```
int i = passedString.lasIndexOf("-");
```

Alternatively, you could use regex to parse the numbers:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(passedString);
String real = "0";
String imag = "0";
if(m.find()){
  real = m.group(0);
  if(m.find()){
     imag = m.group(0);
  }
 }

MyDouble realNum = new MyDouble(Double.parseDouble(real));
MyDouble imagNum = new MyDouble(Double.parseDouble(imag));

cn = new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum);
```

"-?" will optionally search for a leading negative sign, "\\d" will look for a digit, and "+" will look for that number one or more times

Answer (score 0):

My solution in scala is just for integer complex numbers:

```
case class Complex(rel: Int, img: Int)
case class Triplet(sign: String, weight: Int, coord: Char) // -10i is ("-", -10, i)
val pattern = "([+-])?(\\d*)i?".r
//let say the following string is complex number
val cplxStr = "1 + j"
def triplet(part: String) = {
    def intOf(l: String): Int =  if(l == "") 1 else l.toInt

    val pattern(sn, w, c) = part
    if(part isEmpty) Triplet("", 0, "")
    else if(sn == "-") Triplet(sn,-1*intOf(w), c)
    else Triplet(sn,intOf(w),c)
}
val parts = s.replace("-", "+-").split("\\+").map(triplet)

var coeffs:Array[Int] = new Array(2)
for(Triplet(s,w,c) <- parts){
   if(c == "i") coeffs(1) = w
   else  coeffs(0) = w
}
Complex(coeffs(0), coeffs(1))
```

It can be adapted to double by changing the parsers. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Complex parse(String s) {
    if (s == "i") return new Complex(1);
    String[] temp = {};
    double res_real, res_imag;
    boolean real_nega = false, imag_nega = false; 
    String realString = null;
    String imagString = null;
    if (s.charAt(0) == '-') {
        s = s.substring(1);
        real_nega = true;
    }
    if (Global.isDigit(s.charAt(0))) {
        if (s.contains("i")) {
            temp = new String[2];
            temp[0] = "0";
            temp[1] = s.split("i")[0];
            imag_nega = real_nega;
            real_nega = false;
        }
        else {
            temp = new String[2];
            temp[0] = s;
            temp[1] = "0";
        }
    }
    if (s.contains("+")) {
        temp = s.split("\\+");
    }
    else if (s.contains("-")) {
        temp = s.split("-");
        imag_nega = true;
    }
    if (temp[0].contains("i")) {
        realString = temp[1];
        imagString = temp[0].trim().split("i")[0];
    }
    else {
        realString = temp[0];
        imagString = temp[1].trim().split("i")[0];
    }
    res_real = Double.parseDouble(realString);
    res_imag = Double.parseDouble(imagString);
    if (real_nega) res_real = -res_real;
    if (imag_nega) res_imag = -res_imag;
    return new Complex(res_real, res_imag);
}
```